# Bootstrap Auto Close Dynamically Added Alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

So I add this code dynamically when the user clicks a button (`data` is passed in as a parameter from an AJAX call, that all works fine):

```
$('#container').append('
<div class=" alert alert-danger alert-dismissable fade in" role="alert">    
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
    <h4>Error</h4>
    <p>'+data+'</p>
</div>');`
```

I was wondering if it was possible to add functionality to auto close this alert after a certain time. I know there are other ways to go about doing this where I could easy accomplish this, I'm just looking to do it this way because I want to have multiple alerts when the same button is clicked, so having each alert handle itself and disappear automatically would make it look a lot cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you can use setTimeout Javascript function:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.